# How to manipulate an e-mail with apple MailKit on macOS Monterey

Tags: swift, apple-mail, macos-monterey

Together with macOs Monterey apple published MailKit for apple Mail. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mailkit)

I would like to create an apple Mail extension that can manipulate the from address depending on the to address of a new E-Mail.

I created an extension that include a compose session handler:

"A compose session handler validates recipient email addresses, displays a view controller on Mail’s compose windows, confirms if messages are suitable for delivery, and adds custom headers."

The compose session has a property with the content of the e-mail: MEMessage (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mailkit/memessage) unfortunately all properties of MEMessage are readonly properties.

Is there a different way to manipulate the content of the mail?

*Why i would like to have a function to manipulate the from address:*

I have quite a long list of from E-Mail Addresses. Every E-Mail Account on my mailserver has a wildcard option so next to user@domain.tld you could also use user_something@domain.tld. I use an unique e-mail address where ever i can. If one E-Mail Address get's to much spam i simply block the Address on the Server.

If the from E-mail Adress is added to apple mail, it will be set automatically when i answer an e-mail that i received. But if i write a new e-mail i have to set the from address manually.

Since only the mail address varies and not the senders name, it's quite hard to select it from the long list. Also whenever i first want to write (or answer) with an e-mail address that is not added to the settings, i need to add it in the settings first. I was hoping that i could write an add-on to simplify this process.

This would also be nice if you have lot's of different e-mail accounts. E.g one private, one for work. Than you could maintain a list of receivers with the depending from address.

Comment: What does the documentation say? Does it allow you to change the contents of the email? Why do you need such thing?

Comment: Hey @Cristik, judging from my understanding of the documentation, it is not possible to manipulate the content of the email. It is only possible to add additional headers. But maybe i'm simply missing something.